# Redirect windows process to new URL

Tags: url, redirect, url-interception

How do I redirect a program to connect to a different URL.

I looked at this post:  [Is it possible to redirect a url to another using a webproxy ( such as fiddler )](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/989282/is-it-possible-to-redirect-a-url-to-another-using-a-webproxy-such-as-fiddler)

I installed fidller on the machine and put this code in the custom rules in the onBeforeResponse method

```
            oSession.utilDecodeResponse();
var oBody =System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetString(oSession.responseBodyBytes);

// Replace all instances of the DIV tag with an empty string
var oRegEx = "myoldurl.com";
oBody = oBody.replace(oRegEx, "testingurl.com");

       // Set the response body to the div-less string
     oSession.utilSetResponseBody(oBody);
```

I need to do this so I can test our new server service at a testing url and make sure the client software still interacts appropriately.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out how to do it.  :)  I guess it helps to read the Fiddler Documentation.

I added

```
if (oSession.HTTPMethodIs("CONNECT") && (oSession.PathAndQuery == "www.example.com:443")) { 
    oSession.PathAndQuery = "beta.example.com:443"; 
}

if (oSession.HostnameIs("www.example.com")) oSession.hostname = "beta.example.com";
```

to the `OnBeforeRequest`

I found this at http://www.fiddler2.com/fiddler/dev/scriptsamples.asp